# If my website in in WP, can i install CiviCRM in drupal?

Tags: drupal

Our NP site is made with WP, i did install Civicrm but wasnt a fan of how it looked, i learned there is a theme but its only for the drupal version.

I installed drupal as a subdomain and was planning to install Civicrm. Is there any reason to have CRM on the same CMS?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! What Masswear says is not right. You can have your website in wordpress and have CiviCRM in a Drupal installation.

You can the connect your wordpress site to civicrm with a plugin called [CiviMcRestFace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/connector-civicrm-mcrestface/). This plugin creates an api connection to civicrm. So you need an API key (of the civicrm user) and the site key.

When you want to send signup forms to civicrm you can then use Caldera Forms and [Integration of CiviCRM Form Processor with Caldera forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm-formprocessor/). You then also need the [Form Processor extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor/) in CiviCRM.

I believe that the [Contact Form 7 CiviCRM Integration plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/) also works with CiviRestFace. But I am not sure about that what I do know is that it connect to an external CiviCRM

When you want to display data from your drupal CiviCRM installation you can use the wpDataTable plugin and the [Data Source CiviCRM api for wpDataTable](https://wordpress.org/plugins/data-source-civicrm-api-for-wpdatatable/) plugin to display data from a civicrm as a table on your word press pages. Eventually you can use the [Data Processor extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor) in CiviCRM to create custom api's through the user interface.

Answer (score -3):

Welcome! If your website is made with Wordpress and you would like to integrate civiCRM with this website, you have to use the Plugin for wordpress. If you want to use Drupal, you will need to create the website with Drupal as well. You might want to look into this Wordpress-Plugin that supplies a theme for CiviCRM admin screens that is more in keeping with WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/

Comment: Masswear, this used to be a year ago and has evolved during last year as I am involved in a few projects where CiviCRM is behind a firewall and wordpress is the public facing website with forms for entering data into civicrm and shows tables/maps with data from civicrm.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that, thank you!